# How do I query a polymorphic pivot table with Eloquent & Laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables. 1 that defines videos, 1 that defines carousels and 1 pivot table that defines which carousel a video belongs to if it even belongs to any.

I have tried to describe my tables below in as simple a way as possible

- Videos Table

id title user

- Feature Table (Pivot)

id carousel_id video_id

- Carousel Table

id carousel_type

How can I query the database for all videos in the Feature table with a given carousel type using Eloquent models relations. I am using Laravel 5 if that makes a difference. I have tried the morphMany as described in their documentation but I must be doing something wrong.

Thanks!

Edit:

Table names:

videos,
features,
carousels

Model names:

Video,
Feature,
Carousel

#

Edit 2:
Tables:
casts,features,featureables
Models:Cast, Feature

Here are the files that I am currently having trouble with.

Controller:

```
class castController extends Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $carousel_casts = \App\Feature::find(1)->casts;
        foreach($carousel_casts as $casts){
            echo $casts->title . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function casts()
{
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Cast','featureables'); 
}
```

I have specific table names for a reason, I am taking over a pre existing project and the table names can't change. The current tables are casts(video), features(the carousel table), featureables(the pivot table).

I can query all of these tables seperatly without issue, however when I use the belongsToMany relationship I get the following error.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'featureables.feature_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `casts`.*, `featureables`.`feature_id` as `pivot_feature_id`, `featureables`.`cast_id` as `pivot_cast_id` from `casts` inner join `featureables` on `casts`.`id` = `featureables`.`cast_id` where `featureables`.`feature_id` = 1)

Comment: Can you provide the names of your tables and models?

Comment: I have just added them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rename `features` table to `carousel_video`.

Next, define relationship in your `Carousel` model like:

```php
public function videos()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('YourAppNamespace\Video');
}
```

Then, query the `Carousel` model like:

```php
$videos = Carousel::find(2)->videos; //finds all videos associated with carousel having id of 2

return $videos;
```

You can do the opposite by defining a relationship on your `Video` model like:

```php
public function carousels()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('YourAppNamespace\Carousel');
}
```

And, querying like:

```php
$carousels = Video::find(2)->carousels; //finds all carousels associated with video having id of 2

return $carousels;
```

Comment: I can't figure out how this will work if we don't reference the carousel_video table? I guess I will have to try it out and report back, thanks!

Comment: Laravel does using its own magic. See here [Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many)

Comment: Thanks! will try this tonight and then accept your answer!

Comment: This works great, however when I change the table names and model names etc to work on my actual project it errors, even though I used the second parameter on belongsToMany so it locates the pivot table. Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: Can you post your files so we can see your actual code? If not, at least provide the error, table names and model names, please.

Comment: I have just added some more detail to my orignal post

Comment: Is there a feature_id column on featureables table?

Comment: Ah, stupid me. It is not named that as it is a pivot table for other "video" tables too. How to I specify the column name for it to join on?

Comment: You can override the associated keys by adding them as your second and third arguments on the model relationship.